# cordova.plugins.diagnostic not working on newly created App

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap

Just installed cordova plugin on my new project. `cordova plugin add cordova.plugins.diagnostic` I successfully added it.

Then I test it first using this basic code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        function log(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            document.body.innerHTML += '<p>' + msg + '</p><br><br><br><br>';
        }

        function onReady() {
            log("deviceready");
            try {
                cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled(function(enabled) {
                    log("Location enabled: " + enabled);
                }, function(error) {
                    log("A plugin error occurred: " + error);
                });
            } catch (e) {
                log("An exception occurred: " + e.message);
            }
        }
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onReady, false);
    </script>
```

After running the code on browser and on my andriod phone using phonegap mobile developer. I got an error.
`An exception occurred: Cannot read property 'diagnostic' of undefined`. I tried building apk of the app, the same is the error. What could be the problem?

Here are my plugin list:
`cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"`
`cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.2 "Geolocation"`
`cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.2.0 "InAppBrowser"`
`cordova-plugin-network-information 2.0.2 "Network Information"`
`cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.3.0 "Request Location Accuracy"`
`cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.4 "Whitelist"`
`cordova.plugins.diagnostic 5.0.1 "Diagnostic"`

And my config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.test.location" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Test</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" spec="~2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" spec="~4.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" spec="~2.3.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~3.2.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="~2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova.plugins.diagnostic"/>
</widget>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After running the code on browser and on my andriod phone using phonegap mobile developer

[As documented](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin#native-environment-required), the plugin only supports native Android & iOS environments so will not work with the browser platform or phonegap developer app (which is pre-compiled).

To use this plugin you will need to build and run the app on the native mobile platform:

```
cordova platform add android && cordova run android
cordova platform add ios && cordova run ios
```

Comment: Hi @davealden Thank you for this. I have new issue regarding the geolocation plugin. When I run navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition I go an error: `code 1 illegal access`. What might be the problem? I tried removing and adding the plugin or the android platform. Same error exists.